# faster (and less precise) alternatives to dd

Tags: dd

Sometimes `dd` takes too long and I don't actually need byte by byte exact hdd replicas.

I was thinking of resizing the partition in question to the minimum free space possible and then running `dd` so it would only copy the actual files;
Or zipping works quite nice, especially if that partition was formatted beforehand and had lots of blank spaces with 0s

But are there any other alternatives to backup only the files (I love to restore windows with dd, but images are big), or wipe unused space before `dd`|`gzip`, or just make `dd` faster sacrificing unallocated partition space?

Comment: If you just want to copy files, use rsync. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/rsync

Answer (score 3):

If you prefer a full, mountable, image backup, then `e2image` has gained the ability to copy the filesystem with data, skipping the free space in 14.04.  Of course, `tar` or `dump` also lets you do incremental backups.

Comment: It appears that gparted now uses `e2image -ra` to move ext4 partitions to the left on a drive.